# type annotation for class variables

Tags: python, cython

In the following code, how can I use pure python syntax to annotate the type of `self.a` in cython?

```
class C:
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1
  @cython.locals(x = int)
  def f(self, x):
    self.a += x
```

Comment: have you tried something like `self.a = cython.declare(cython.int);self.a = 1`?

Comment: @mgilson won't work. error is  'declare' not a valid cython attribute or is being used incorrectly

Comment: @leon: What's the actual code you used for mgilson's comment? Because for me, with Cython 0.19, in either Python 2.7.2 or 3.3.0, putting that line inside `__init__` worked (as in it had no effect in pure Python except to set `self.a` to `0` before setting it to `1`).

Comment: Never mind, when I compile anything that uses it, I get the same error…

Comment: *sigh* Thought I would take a stab at it :)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, both with Cython 0.16 and 0.19.1

```
import cython

@cython.cclass
class C(object):
    a=cython.declare(cython.int)
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    @cython.locals(x = int)
    def f(self, x):
        self.a += x
    def val(self):
        return self.a
```

As you can see `cython.declare` should be used in the class instead in `__init__`.